# php multilevel menu dropdown getting childs child

Tags: php

I m writing a multilevel menu with the below code im able to get only the parent category and

it s child ,I NEED to get the childs child and so on and so forth

Please help me out::

```
$resultMainMenu = mysql_query("SELECT menu.menu_id,menu.menu_name,menu.parent_id FROM 
menu,menu_users WHERE menu.parent_id=0 
 AND menu.something='x'
AND menu_users.menu_id = menu.menu_id AND menu_users.user_type=1 ") or die(mysql_error());


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($resultMainMenu)){

    echo $row['menu_name'] . '<br />'; // echo main menu

    $resultSubmenu = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE parent_id='". $row['menu_id']."' AND menu.something='x'") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($resultSubmenu) >= 1){

        while($rowSub = mysql_fetch_array($resultSubmenu)){

            echo ' -- ' . $rowSub['menu_name'] . '<br />'; // echo sub menu

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How many layers of menu nesting to do you want to support? 1? 2? 10? infinite?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by rewriting your code like the following recursive function.

```
$resultMainMenu = mysql_query("SELECT menu.menu_id,menu.menu_name,menu.parent_id FROM 
menu,menu_users WHERE menu.parent_id=0 
 AND menu.something='x'
AND menu_users.menu_id = menu.menu_id AND menu_users.user_type=1 ") or die(mysql_error());

recur($resultMainMenu, "");

function recur($result, $preFormat) {
  if(mysql_num_rows($result) >= 1){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

      echo $preFormat . $row['menu_name'] . '<br />'; // echo main menu

      $newResult = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM menu WHERE parent_id='". $row['menu_id']."' 
                   AND menu.something='x'") or die(mysql_error());

      recur($newResult, $preFormat . " -- ");
    }
  }
}
```